# Generate small-world model in igraph using Newman-Watts algorithm

Tags: igraph

I want to generate small-world networks using `igraph`, but not using "rewiring" as implemented in the `watts.strogatz.game()`. In the Newman variation all local links are fixed but a fixed number of random links are lifted and dropped randomly on the network at a fixed rate (basically adding "long-range" connections). I thought I could simply generate a lattice (e.g. `g <- graph.lattice(length=20, dim=1, circular=TRUE)`) and then put a classical random graph on top of that. However, I do not know how to do this using a graph as input argument. Or maybe it is possible to add random edges at a specified probability?

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use `graph.lattice` to generate a lattice, then `erdos.renyi.game` with the same number of vertices and a fixed probability to generate a random graph. Then you can combine the two graphs using the `%u%` (union) operator. There is a small chance for multi-edges if the same edge happens to be the part of the lattice and the random graph as well, so you should also call `simplify()` on the union if you don't want that.

Comment: Fab! Sounds easy enough. Thanks a lot for the help, Tamas!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick, in case anyone is interested. Just have to create a function to do this "rewiring" over and over again. Many thanks again, Tamas!

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.lattice(length=100, dim=1, circular=TRUE)
g2 <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 1/100)
g3 <- g %u% g2
g3 <- simplify(g3)
plot.igraph(g3, vertex.size = 1,vertex.label = NA, layout=layout_in_circle)
```